Indicability of $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$
A group $G$ is said to be indicable if it surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}$.

If $n=1$: $\mathrm{Out}(F_1)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and no finite group surjects onto an infinite group.

If $n\geq 4$:  $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$ has Kazhdan's property (T) so it is not indicable.


But, how about $\mathrm{Out}(F_3)$?

Wait, in the $n=2$ case isn't the abelianization also finite? I don't think any of them are indicable.

@MattZaremsky True, I made a mistake in the computations... thanks!!

Shall we assume that "surjects" refers to a surjective homomorphism, or does it mean any surjective map onto ℤ ?

Nielsen gave a finite presentation of $\operatorname{Aut}(F_n)$ 100 years ago and from that you can compute that the abelianization of $\operatorname{Aut}(F_3)$ is order 2, so no, $\operatorname{Out}(F_3)$ is not indicable. It is however virtually indicable. McCool showed that $\operatorname{Out}(F_3)$ is virtually residually torsion-free nilpotent and Grunewald-Lubotzky showed that it is large (virtually surjects onto a non-abelian free group) in their Corollary 9.3.
McCool, James, A faithful polynomial representation of (\text{Out }F_3)., Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 106, No. 2, 207-213 (1989). ZBL0733.20031.
Grunewald, Fritz; Lubotzky, Alexander, Linear representations of the automorphism group of a free group., Geom. Funct. Anal. 18(2008), No. 5, 1564-1608 (2009). ZBL1175.20028.
